# TypeError: Object(...) is not a function with "useCallBack" , in React Version 16.13.1

Tags: reactjs, object, usecallback

I get an error message on my localhost port on the browser, I haven't deployed yet my code:

TypeError: Object(...) is not a function

NewEvent
src/events/pages/NewEvent.js:51

---

Here my react versions in package.json:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-router-dom": "5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "^3.2.0",
    "react-transition-group": "^4.4.1"
  },
```

I have import in my pages NewEvent.js :

```
import React, {useCallBack , useReducer} from 'react';
```

In the same page I have nested in a function another function:

```
  const [formState, dispatch] = useReducer(formReducer, {
    inputs: {
      title: {
        value: '',
        isValid: false
      },
      description: {
        value: '',
        isValid: false
      }
    },
    isValid: false
  });// this is the initial state that needs  to be update in the reducer

  const inputHandler = useCallBack((id,value,isValid) => {
 
  dispatch({
    type: 'INPUT_CHANGE',
    value: value,
    isValid: isValid,
    inputId: id,
   });
 }, []);
```

The issue shows in the browser is the following line :

```
  const inputHandler = useCallBack((id,value,isValid) => {
```

> > > useCallBack is supposed to stop the code to loop when there is several function..
> > > I checked online in other post it seems to be link with the version of react, but I am not sure and quite confused.

Here the messages in the console:

```
log.js:24 [HMR] Waiting for update signal from WDS...
NewEvent.js:51 Uncaught TypeError: Object(...) is not a function

    at NewEvent (NewEvent.js:51)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:14803)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:17482)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:18596)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:188)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:237)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:292)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:23203)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:22154)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:22130)
    at performSyncWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js:21756)
    at scheduleUpdateOnFiber (react-dom.development.js:21188)
    at updateContainer (react-dom.development.js:24373)
    at react-dom.development.js:24758
    at unbatchedUpdates (react-dom.development.js:21903)
    at legacyRenderSubtreeIntoContainer (react-dom.development.js:24757)
    at Object.render (react-dom.development.js:24840)
    at Module../src/index.js (index.js:7)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:784)
    at fn (bootstrap:150)
    at Object.1 (Users.js:19)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:784)
    at checkDeferredModules (bootstrap:45)
    at Array.webpackJsonpCallback [as push] (bootstrap:32)
    at main.chunk.js:1
index.js:1 The above error occurred in the <NewEvent> component:
    in NewEvent (at App.js:23)
    in Route (at App.js:22)
    in Switch (at App.js:15)
    in main (at App.js:14)
    in Router (created by BrowserRouter)
    in BrowserRouter (at App.js:11)
    in App (at src/index.js:7)

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
react-dom.development.js:22665 Uncaught TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
    at NewEvent (NewEvent.js:51)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:14803)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:17482)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:18596)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:188)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:237)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:292)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:23203)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:22154)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:22130)
    at performSyncWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js:21756)
    at scheduleUpdateOnFiber (react-dom.development.js:21188)
    at updateContainer (react-dom.development.js:24373)
    at react-dom.development.js:24758
    at unbatchedUpdates (react-dom.development.js:21903)
    at legacyRenderSubtreeIntoContainer (react-dom.development.js:24757)
    at Object.render (react-dom.development.js:24840)
    at Module../src/index.js (index.js:7)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:784)
    at fn (bootstrap:150)
    at Object.1 (Users.js:19)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:784)
    at checkDeferredModules (bootstrap:45)
    at Array.webpackJsonpCallback [as push] (bootstrap:32)
    at main.chunk.js:1
```

---

The message showing on the browser :

```
NewEvent
src/events/pages/NewEvent.js:51
  48 |   isValid: false
  49 | });// this is the initial state that needs  to be update in the reducer
  50 | 
> 51 | const inputHandler = useCallBack((id,value,isValid) => {
     | ^  52 | //this function will received the id of the input that changed, value and answer whether it's valid or not
  53 | dispatch({
  54 |   type: 'INPUT_CHANGE',

View compiled
16 stack frames were collapsed.
Module../src/index.js
```

Anyone has an idea of the issue, please?

-- Sorry my post is very long -- :D

Answer (score 8):

So I spent some time attempting to recreate this error to eventually realize this is an unfortunate case of a *typo*.

In short, do this: `import React, { useCallback, useReducer } from "react";` (notice the lowercase ***b*** in callback).

It's hard to glean what the actual error is, given only this much information: `TypeError: undefined is not a function`.

However, the MDN [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Not_a_function) on TypeError's (among other things) states:

> Maybe there is a typo in the function name?

Hope this helps!

Comment: Oh my god! Thank you for your help!!!
Yes, indeed it is the issue ! Thanx a lot! Have a good day!

Comment: Great Thanks, buddy.